# High Dimensional function optimization for slow functions

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, multidimensional-array, evolutionary-algorithm

I am not really sure if this is the right place to ask this, but since it didnt seem to be a perfect fit for the mathematics SX either, I decided to post here.

I have function with a very high dimension (250+) and need to find the optimum or at least some approximation.

I am aware of approaches like PSO, differential evolution, Simulated Annealing and so on. The problem in my specific case is that calculating a single function value can take up to several hours. So there is a need for a smarter approach.

First intuition is to reduce the dimensions and thats what I am currently working on. But I wondered if there are some published papers about a similar problem describing a working approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a surface response model to approximate your function:

- You use the firt evaluations of your function to build an approximate model,
- You then use the approximate model as evaluation function,
- Some of the evaluations have to be performed with the real function, and you'll use the result to refine your model, and so on.

Comment: do you know of any tools I could use for this? There seems to be the Matlab SuMo Toolbox (http://www.sumowiki.intec.ugent.be/index.php/Main_Page) but the last update was quite some time ago. Is there something similar for a free platform? Python or R for example?